# values are not getting display in jsp

Tags: java, html, jsp, el

I started learning jsp and I have written a `form.jsp` which contains some fields, and I have another page called `formResult.jsp`.
I am trying to display the value of `form.jsp` to `formResult.jsp` using `El(Expression Language)`.
I dont know what is wrong with my code, the value are not getting populated from `form.jsp` to `formResult.jsp` except `fName`(First Name).
This is very annoying and abnormal. I don't know what to do.
Please help me.

**form.jsp**

```html
<form action="formResult.jsp">
<fieldset>
  <legend>
   <font face="Courier New" size="+1" 
     color="red">
  Please enter your information
   </font>
 </legend> 
</fieldset>
<table>
<tr>
 <td>First Name:</td>
 <td><input type="text" name="fName"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>Last Name:</td>
 <td><input type="text" name="lName"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>Email:</td>
 <td><input type="text" name="email">
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>Address</td>
 <td><textarea rows="3" cols="20" name="address"></textarea>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="submit" value="SUBMIT"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

With all the possible way I tried. the bellow three ways are not working.I am just getting the first value
**formResult.jsp**

```html
    <body>
    First Name :${param.fName}<br>
    Last Name :${param.lName}<br>
    Email :${param.email}<br>
    Address :${param.address}<br>

    First Name :${param["fName"]}<br>
    Last Name :${param["lName"]}<br>
    Email :${param["email"]}<br>
    Address     :${param["address"]}<br>
    
    First Name :${param[0]}<br>
    Last Name :${param[1]}<br>
    Email :${param[2]}<br>
    Address    :${param[3]}<br>
    </body>
```

**Input**
[image]

**Output**
[image]

Comment: Spelling mistakes: "parma" -> "param"

Comment: varun: Flag this comment for serious problems or moderator attention

Comment: @R Lam I Corrected it but still its not working

Comment: I think you should try to use java to printout first. <%=request.getParameter("xxxx")%>

Comment: @R Lam I dont want  to use scriptlet  tag. I want to use EL(Expression Language)

Comment: Yeah I know. But this can help you to solve this issue. If it works on Java, then it should be your environment causes problem (e.g missing library or sth)

Comment: @R Lam Then why its working for the first value????

Comment: You reduced the HTML for this question (thanks). You might search for `</form>` (maybe you had a nested form? Or more likely the page is XHTML meaning that `<input ... />` should have a final slash (the following fields were nested inside the first input. Do `<form ... method="post">`

Comment: @joop Eggen i have put the <input ... /> but still its not working

Comment: Then it is something really silly. Try outputting first lName or address i.o. fName, Check the HTML source text. Type `${param.xxx}` again.

Comment: Your markup is wrong. You are missing closing `<td>` tags in Email and Address fields. Is this the whole JSP page?

Comment: I'm unsure about the last part, param[0], param[1] etc, but the first two ways should work. Does not look like any issue exist there. Can you try to see if browser is setting all parameters properly through capturing requests on Firebug?

Comment: You are knowingly or unknowingly sending an HTTP GET request, here `<form action="formResult.jsp">` (the default `method` is `GET` - `method="GET"`) wherein all input values which are supposed to be sent as request parameters are actually not submitted. You may want to raise an HTTP POST request anyway or append those values as query-string parameters.

Comment: @PavanKumar I have check in Firebug data are coming but not populated in formResult.jsp

Comment: @Tiny shouldn't matter if GET or POST. They all work the same way here.

Comment: @varun, Its really weird, - which server are you working with? Can you try googling if this server has any issues that way - J2EE is implemented by server environment and behaviors can differ between various ones. I tried with Tomcat 8 on windows and it worked (excluding ${param[0]} kind of representations).

Comment: During GET requests, the form itself is not submitted. Therefore, no request parameters are available on the server through `HttpServletRequest#getParameter/Values("paramName")` as the OP is likely to have assumed incorrectly. The only way to obtain them is to supply them as query-string parameters, abusively store them into `HttpSession` or get an HTTP POST request to be raised anyway. @PavanKumar

Comment: @Tiny Exactly, query string is the way with GET and in current case, each of the input fields have name and hence query string on the formResult.jsp will have all the parameters input by the user.

Comment: @varun I have copied your code and it is working just fine.